# Arduino wav playback plays too fast

Tags: arduino, wav

I'm trying to play a wav file from the microSD card reader. I tried using SimpleSDAudio and TMRpcm libraries but the playback is a way too fast. The song which lasts 3 minutes is played in 1 second.

I'm using Arduino Uno and Ethernet Shield with microSD card reader built-in. Speaker is connected to  the pin 9.

```
#include <SimpleSDAudio.h>
void setup()
{ 
  // SdPlay.setSDCSPin(10); // Enable if your SD card CS-Pin is not at Pin 4... 
  SdPlay.init(SSDA_MODE_HALFRATE | SSDA_MODE_MONO | SSDA_MODE_AUTOWORKER);
  SdPlay.setFile("track.wav"); 
  SdPlay.play();
}

void loop(void) {
}
```

Comment: What is the exact code you are using? It seems you are using the wrong sampling rate. Do you know the sampling rate of the original wav? 180x speedup is unusual... are you sure you are reading the entire file? Could you be running into a memory issue (32 k RAM, 1 second... not impossible)

Comment: The wav is mono, the rate is 8k and the encoding is unsigned 8 bit PCM. The song is played in ~15 seconds (my mistake, I loaded wrong file). When I changed  SSDA_MODE_FULLRATE to a SSDA_MODE_HALFRATE it plays longer but it's still too fast).

Comment: I've found the solution, the advice is to change the sampling rate. Thanks Floris, your comment guided me to the answer

Comment: Could you show what you did to change the sampling rate- it might help future visitors!

Comment: Sure. I used the SoX (`sox inputfile.wav --norm=-1 -e unsigned-integer -b 8 -r 31250 -c 1 -t wav outputfile.wav`) to convert the file to wav with correct sampling rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the library you use cannot play 8k sample files - see http://www.hackerspace-ffm.de/wiki/index.php?title=SimpleSDAudio . The slowest rate is 32k (depending on clock rate on your board) - so you are getting a 4x speed increase just from that.

It is also possible that your buffer isn't large enough. Does it play the whole file, or does it stop before the end? You might want to use

```
getLastError();
```

to find out if errors caused the playback to stop too soon (is the file fragmented? You need a cleanly formatted SD card and must not have deleted any files on it otherwise it will get confused and corrupted). See the above link for more details.